# How to create User defined Datatype with %TYPE and %ROWTYPE in PGAdmin 4

Tags: sql, postgresql

Being new to PostgreSQL & PGAdmin 4, I am not being able to create a `TYPE` with data type containing `%TYPE` to any other table's column(referenced item). PGAdmin 4 GUI is only giving option to use any primitive datatypes.

### What PgAdmin is allowing:

```
CREATE TYPE logindetails AS
(
    accesscode smallint,
    displayname character varying(50)
);
```

### What I need:

```
CREATE TYPE logindetails AS
(
    accesscode moduleaccess.access_level%type,
    displayname usermaster.user_name%type);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,
Abhirup.

Comment: That's not possible. Postgres doesn't allow this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html

Comment: Thanks for your help..! :) Will do in alternative way.